# LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'mfc90ud.lib' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library

Tags: visual-c++

This warning seems to be related to a runtime error I'm having.  If I ignore this warning, I get an exception when using a method in a library.  If I try to fix this warning using the /NODEFAULTLIB switch, I'm not able to build because of undefined symbols.

[image]

Comment: you can add some code or screen shot might help us to understand the problem

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem.  There was a mismatch between the character set in the static library, and the character set in the application.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mweaa.png)